# Xamarin PCL Project doesn't launch or add an icon after deploying the app to an Android device

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I created a Xamarin Forms PCL Project in Visual Studio and worked with an iPad Air 2 until now to create & test my app. When I press F5 in Visual Studio while having the iOS Project as startup project, the remote Mac successfully transfers the compiled app to the attached iPad.

Now I wanted to test the app with both an emulated Android device and a real device, but with both devices I have the problem that I can not start the app as there is no icon on both the homescreen or the launcher app list that I could press on to start it or use the debugger as no app gets started.

According to Visual Studio the app is successfully deployed.

```
1>Starting deploy KA_AVD_Tablet_1280x800_10.1 ...
1>Starting emulator KA_AVD_Tablet_1280x800_10.1 ...
1>C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd KA_AVD_Tablet_1280x800_10.1 -prop monodroid.avdname=KA_AVD_Tablet_1280x800_10.1
1>Hax is enabled
1>Hax ram_size 0x40000000
1>HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
1>emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
1>emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
1>Emulator KA_AVD_Tablet_1280x800_10.1 is running.
1>Deploying KA_AVD_Tablet_1280x800_10.1 ...
1>Build started.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE;__XAMARIN_ANDROID_v1_0__;__MOBILE__;__ANDROID__;__ANDROID_1__;__ANDROID_2__;__ANDROID_3__;__ANDROID_4__;__ANDROID_5__;__ANDROID_6__;__ANDROID_7__;__ANDROID_8__;__ANDROID_9__;__ANDROID_10__;__ANDROID_11__;__ANDROID_12__;__ANDROID_13__;__ANDROID_14__;__ANDROID_15__;__ANDROID_16__;__ANDROID_17__;__ANDROID_18__;__ANDROID_19__;__ANDROID_20__;__ANDROID_21__;__ANDROID_22__;__ANDROID_23__;__ANDROID_24__;__ANDROID_25__ /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>DC.Xam.MyApp\DC.Xam.MyApp\bin\Debug\DC.Xam.MyApp.dll /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\ExifLib.PCL.1.0.1\lib\portable-net45+sl50+win+WindowsPhoneApp81+wp80+Xamarin.iOS10+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10\ExifLib.dll /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.175\lib\MonoAndroid10\FormsViewGroup.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Java.Interop.dll" /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\modernhttpclient.2.4.2\lib\MonoAndroid\ModernHttpClient.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v7.1\Mono.Android.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v7.1\Mono.Android.Export.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll" /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.dll /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\modernhttpclient.2.4.2\lib\MonoAndroid\OkHttp.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.dll /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid43\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.dll /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.dll /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.dll /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.dll /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.dll /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.175\lib\MonoAndroid10\Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\Xamarin.Forms.Pages.2.3.3.175\lib\MonoAndroid10\Xamarin.Forms.Pages.dll /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.175\lib\MonoAndroid10\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.175\lib\MonoAndroid10\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Base.1.0.0.43-pre1\lib\MonoAndroid10\Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Android.dll /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Base.1.0.0.43-pre1\lib\MonoAndroid10\Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Base.dll /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Dark.1.0.0.43-pre1\lib\MonoAndroid10\Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Dark.dll /reference:<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.175\lib\MonoAndroid10\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.AccessControl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.AppContext.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Collections.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Collections.Specialized.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ComponentModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Console.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Data.Common.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Data.SqlClient.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Process.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.TraceEvent.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Drawing.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Globalization.Calendars.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Globalization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Globalization.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.FileSystem.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.Pipes.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Linq.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Linq.Expressions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Linq.Parallel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Linq.Queryable.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.AuthenticationManager.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Cache.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.HttpListener.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Mail.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.NameResolution.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Ping.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Requests.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Security.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.ServicePoint.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Sockets.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Utilities.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.WebSockets.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ObjectModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Resources.ReaderWriter.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Handles.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.AccessControl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Claims.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.DeriveBytes.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Encryption.Aes.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Encryption.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Encryption.ECDiffieHellman.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Encryption.ECDsa.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Principal.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.SecureString.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Http.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Security.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.AccessControl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.Thread.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.Timer.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.XDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.XPath.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.Xsl.Primitives.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\DCXamMyAppDroid.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /target:library /utf8output MainActivity.cs Resources\Resource.Designer.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\Users\Kia\AppData\Local\Temp\MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs
1>DC.Xam.MyApp.Droid -> <PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>DC.Xam.MyApp\DC.Xam.MyApp.Droid\bin\Debug\DCXamMyAppDroid.dll
1>No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
1>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\tabbar.xml
1>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\tabs.xml
1>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\toolbar.xml
1>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\styles.xml
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\\bin\keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keystore "C:\Users\Kia\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\\bin\jarsigner.exe -keystore "C:\Users\Kia\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg md5withRSA -signedjar bin\Debug\\com.mycompany.DCXamMyApp-Signed-Unaligned.apk <PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>DC.Xam.MyApp\DC.Xam.MyApp.Droid\obj\Debug\android\bin\com.mycompany.DCXamMyApp.apk androiddebugkey 
1>No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2046-12-29) or after any future revocation date.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\zipalign.exe 4 "<PATH_TO_PROJECTROOT>DC.Xam.MyApp\DC.Xam.MyApp.Droid\bin\Debug\com.mycompany.DCXamMyApp-Signed-Unaligned.apk" "bin\Debug\\com.mycompany.DCXamMyApp-Signed.apk" 
1>Build succeeded.
1>Deploy successfully on KA_AVD_Tablet_1280x800_10.1
```

And the App is installed under "Apps" in Settings.

[image: App List]

But nowhere else

[image]

I tried adding a standalone Android project to the solution and run that which worked perfectly fine.

What could cause my PCL App to not show up anywhere but the App list in the settings?

Answer (score 0):

After further research I could find my problem.

In the MainActivity.cs of my Android Project the variable "MainLauncher" was set to false.

Changing it to

```
MainLauncher = true
```

makes everything work.